# Optimal Disk Partition Scheme for Normal User

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, lvm

I am new to Linux, I have installed Ubuntu Desktop to my machine, and this post is about Ubuntu Desktop, not Server. However, as I do researches about Ubuntu and learn something about it, I have encountered partition schemes and logical volumes. So, I have some questions on my mind. First of all, my machine is dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. It has 2 disks, 256 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD. I am planning to use Ubuntu as a secondary OS, and I will learn how to use it slowly. Therefore, I have allocated 50 GB in SSD and 150 GB in HDD for Ubuntu, the rest goes for Windows.

1-I have learned that, using separate `/home` directories are good for maintaining the Ubuntu. Also, separating `/opt`, `/var`, `/usr`, `/boot`, and `/tmp` may also be a good idea. However, I do not know what are those directories, what are their purposes. For which ones should I create separate partitions in my disk and for which ones should I create these partitions into SSD? Should I also create the second `/home` directory into a new SSD partition? As I have stated, I have 50 GB on SSD, so I do not have much space for anything to be on SSD. I just want to have some daily-use applications, OS, and some critical programs to be in SSD. According to these, how should I partition my disks?

2-I also learned that LVM is a flexible and good to use feature. But, I do not know which partitions should be LVM, which ones shouldn't. According to the previous question of mine, which partitions should I create as LVM? Some people told that every partition should be LVM, but I do not know about it. I am not planning to add a new disk to my machine, so in that case should every partition be LVM?

As I searched through this platform, I saw similar posts. However, none of them was complete enough to do partitions without hesitation and information. All answers and guides are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about Ubuntu Server (with a specific function in mind), or Ubuntu Desktop.  For Ubuntu Desktop, I wouldn't go beyond having a / and /home partition(s).  For server installations, generally the same will apply, depending on your end-use case.  /opt, /var/, /boot/ & /tmp/ are generally not needed, and I'd suggest avoiding the complexity.  I would have all LVM, or none LVM, and I'd suggest starting without LVM... You'll likely want to start again (either because of a mistake, or just to see how you can *fix* experiments easily via re-install, esp. if desktop)

Comment: @guiverc oh sorry about that, I forgot to specify Ubuntu Desktop. As I have written Normal User in the title, I thought that it is enough. I am editing my post now. Thank you for your answer by the way. I am going to use some heavy applications like Intel Quartus Prime on Ubuntu. So, I wanted to have a good starting in order to prevent the reinstalls. Even if reinstall is required, I do not want to lose data.

Comment: I gently disagree that you are a "normal" user. Your demonstrated knowledge is above average ability. Seems like you are a power-user taking your first bite at Linux. Advice #1: Linux is very different from what you are used to. Embrace those differences. Advice #2: Focus on making your first install *successful* rather than *perfect*. You can add extra features next time (which can be tomorrow if you wish). For a successful first install stick to the installer defaults -- they are sane and safe. Or try installing into a VM for practice.

Comment: @user535733 Oh you are embarassing me now, thank you for your kind comment. I am able to do lots of thing on Windows (which can be found easily on internet by simple searches haha) but I am not an expert of course. However, I always wanted to use Linux distros, so here I am on the road. Also, thank you for your advices. My concern was to do not lose data at every reinstall and guiverc explained lots of useful thing to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said if you're talking about Ubuntu Server (with a specific function in mind), or Ubuntu Desktop.

For Ubuntu Desktop, I wouldn't go beyond having a / and /home partition(s).

For server installations, generally the same will apply, depending on your end-use case.  The directories `/opt`, `/var/`, `/boot/` & `/tmp/` are generally not needed, and I'd suggest avoiding the complexity (especially when learning).

I would have all LVM, or none LVM, and I'd suggest starting without LVM.

You'll likely want to start again (either because of a mistake, or just to see how you can *fix* experiments easily via re-install, esp. if desktop).

Having a simple & easy setup, allows you to re-install easily & get back to operation if you make a mistake (in ~15 minutes via re-install, it can take longer with more potential for more mistakes with a more complex layout).

Everyone makes mistakes, but knowing you can re-construct your system easily & quickly allows you to feel comfortable & try things, as you know you can *pick up the pieces*, plus we often learn more through mistakes.

Keep it simple / KISS

*a single / is simplest yes, but I'd still suggest separate /home*

Comment: Once you're comfortable with things.. esp. if you're talking servers, I'd think about using LVM etc.  Not at the start.

Comment: FYI:  You can re-install a system without loosing data.  Use the *Something else* option, select your existing partitions, and it'll note your packages, erase system directories, install system, attempt to re-add back additional packages you had installed, without touching any user file unless you formatted partitions. You re-install without format to keep data (some server configs will need to be restored as they are stored in system directories, no desktop apps does this)

Comment: thank you for that valuable info. Even if I use single / , I can reinstall the system without losing any data using the options you have mentioned, right?

Comment: Yep.   Ubuntu (and *flavors* of Ubuntu) will respect the /home and not erase/touch user data WHEN no-format is selected. This doesn't apply to all GNU/Linux distributions though, so having a separate /home also gives you the option to move away from Ubuntu should you wish to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more question, I know it is a little bit off-topic but forgive me. Let's say I have separated my `/home`, how can I move from Ubuntu to for example CentOS without losing data? Is the only thing I should do format the `/home` directory that contains OS and install the new OS there?

Comment: The OS will go in the / partition, data goes in /home (particularly $HOME which is `/home/guiverc/` for me, ie. `/home/$USER`).  If you format /home, all user data will be lost; my re-install comment assumed no-format for all partitions for simplicity & brevity.  CentOS is off-topic here; my comment was general which I felt okay (I was thinking Debian to be specific).

Comment: In this case, separating `/home` directory means extracting the `/home` directory under the root directory? So, for example assume I have 2 partitions, one has the OS which means it has the root directory but without `/home`, the other has the `/home` directory right?

Comment: Yep.  If you don't have separate directories mounted, they'll fall back to being placed on the / directory.  /home is where user files go, so for Desktop installs, there is somewhat greater flexibility having it separate (isn't required for Ubuntu though; is beneficial for others, but I think still worth it for some rare recovery circumstances)